# Angular 5 + Keycloak allow anonymous users

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak

I am trying to allow anonymous users to my app and I am using this library: 'keycloak-angular' with Angular 5. In the description it requires me to initialize the app like so:

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: keycloakInitializer,
        multi: true,
        deps: [KeycloakService]
    }

export function keycloakInitializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            await keycloak.init({
                config: {
                    url: 'my-url',
                    realm: 'my-realm',
                    clientId: 'my-client-id'
                },
                initOptions: {
                    onLoad: 'check-sso',
                    checkLoginIframe: false
                }
            });
            resolve();
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Doing so it automatically triggers a login prompt to the keycloak server. Is there any way to trigger login only on demand?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done. When you use a factory provider, angular invokes the factory *when* it resolves the dependency.

To defer the prompt, wrap the function in a factory function that returns the original and provide that.

Here is what that looks like

```
export async function initializeApp(
  keycloak: KeycloakService,
  deferredInitializer: typeof keycloakInitializer
) {
  if (someCondition) {
    const initializer = await deferredInitializer(keycloak);

  }
}
export async function keycloakInitializer(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  await keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: 'my-url',
      realm: 'my-realm',
      clientId: 'my-client-id'
    },
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      checkLoginIframe: false
    }
  });
}

const providers = [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeApp,
    deps: [KeycloakService, keycloakInitializer]
  }
];
```

The actual `keycloakInitializer` function is very poorly written so I am going to refactor it for posterity.

```
export async function keycloakInitializer(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  await keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: 'my-url',
      realm: 'my-realm',
      clientId: 'my-client-id'
    },
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      checkLoginIframe: false
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I have some questions though: when should I call "createKeycloakInitializer" ? When user clicks on login button ? And about this part:  "useFactory: keycloakInitializer" using the last function you wrote the code would not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I had made some mistakes. I fixed most of them. And expanded

Comment: @KangJiYoung13 I realized I over complicated. I removed some indirection

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a custom or guest user form keycloak directly. Set the roles, and access restrictions in keycloak itself. finally you can use angular-oauth2-oidc to make the user login to the app. So if you need to get content of a page, or simply make it accessible for guest users, then log in the guest user with the above created credentials. angular-oauth2-oidc provides several rest resources for login, sign-up, update, delete, add users etc... So you can simply login the guest user. But you'll need an extra security implementation to ensure the guest user in not accessing the secure pages or resources.

Just do

```
npm i angular-oauth2-oidc
```

see this [github](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) repository for more information on it.